# In Java, how does System.out refer to PrintStream class?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner learning Java with some knowledge of C++, and the System.out.println(); is confusing me right now. So System is the class, out is a variable that can call a method?? According to: http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/getStarted/application/objects.html
out is a class variable, and a variable is a storage location in the computer memory that has a type name and content. It's not an object like string  that can use methods like .getLength(). The way the website explains it is that out refers to an instance of PrintStream class, but how?

Comment: Every variable is an "object", in that sense. **Edit:** By your definition - being able to call methods on them - this is true of every variable (though strictly speaking not all variables are objects, as pointed out by @delnan).

Comment: @mellamokb Primitives (`int` and friends) are not objects by most definitions of "object" (including all useful ones, I'd argue). And variables (of reference types) *refer to objects*, they *aren't* objects themselves.

Comment: @mellamokb this is confusing me...

Answer (score 6):

> It's not an object

This is where your reasoning is going wrong. `System.out` *is* (a reference to) an object.

The type of the reference is `PrintStream`, as documented in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out). This means that you can call `PrintStream`'s methods on `System.out`, e.g.:

```
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

`out` doesn't call a method : `out` is a variable holding an object (an instance of `PrintStream`) on which you can call a method.

For example :

```
System.out.println("hey!");
```

You could also do

```
void print(PrintStream ps, Object o) {
    ps.println(o);
}
...
print(System.out, "hey!");
```

Answer (score 1):

Out is a *public static field* of the class named *System*.

Because it's public, you can call methods on it.

Its type is *PrintStream*.

The best way to learn is to read the documentation:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Notice the part at the top where it describes *in*, *out*, and *err*.

Answer (score 1):

More strictly, it's a public static field that is a reference to an object of type `PrintStream`, so yes, you can call methods on it.

Java references are roughly analogous to C pointers (at least in the way they are used, obviously there are significant differences).

Answer (score 0):

System.out is a particular instance of PrintStream, whose output is linked to the equivalent of the C++ stdout

Comment: So it is a variable of System but refers to PrintStream       System(){ PrintStream out=new PrintStream;}   ?

Comment: "attribute" is the right term. It is like having a class System{static PrintStream out=...;}, but it is created and initialised by the java virtual machine

Comment: System.out IS an object, and you can call methods of it - like print()

Comment: It's an object and class variable?

Comment: Yes - it is an object referenced by a class variable

Comment: Classes are like "scaffolding", instances are classes filled with actual data, you need to refer to instances with a variable of some kind otherwise you have no way to access them

Comment: For example, Person is a class. new Person("Freeman Lou") is an instance of person. lou=new Person("Freeman Lou") is a variable holding a reference to an instance

Answer (score 0):

System is a  final class which has a final variable out holding a object of PrintStream class on which we can call println() method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the out parameter in `System.out.println(String args[])` is a static field in `System` class. Whenever a field is declared it should have certain datatype. In this class the out field is defined as `static PrintStream out;`.

It means the datatype of out is `PrintStream` class.In this way `System.out` will actually represents a object of `PrintStream` class. With this object we are calling `println()` method of `PrintStream` class.

Answer (score 0):

Think of System class roughly like this :

```
package java.lang;
public final class System {

    public final static PrintStream out;
}
```

here out is a static final variable of "type" Printstream. 
Since  it is a static variable, we can call it by "ClassName.variableName" without creating any object of System class, so we do System.out.

Now, out is a reference variable of "PrintStream" class. Till now, only this reference variable is created and it is not referring to any "object" of Printstream class.
But System class creates object of PrintStream when it is loaded in memory. 
For this, see methods `initializeSystemClass()` and `setOut0()` in below link which is complete source code of System class. (Dont be overwhelmed by this enormous code, just be assured that there is "new PrintStream()" called inside System (here at line 1095)).

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java

so, when we have an object of PrintStream class, our out reference variable can easily call a method on it, right? This is how we call System.out.println()