# How to call a method from another class like how println is called

Tags: java

I am a beginner in this java community so sorry if this question is so naive. I was wondering how to call a method form another class like how a println method of class System is called by using an object out.

i.e. 
how to use like

**Class.object.method();**
like in
**System.out.println();**

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259058/in-java-how-does-system-out-refer-to-printstream-class

Comment: In your example, `System.out` is an object of type `PrintStream`. The method `println()` is a method of class `PrintStream`, not of class `System`. But it's not clear what question or problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

Thats where you use `static` stuff like

```
class Class {
  public static AnotherClass object = new AnotherClass();
}

class AnotherClass {
  public void method() { 
    //... 
  }
}
```

Comment: This is closely related to the Singleton pattern.

Comment: Not really, you wouldnt be disallowing neither the creation of new instances nor ensuring `Class.object` is unique

Comment: Yes, it is not a singleton. But it is still a related pattern: You provide access to a well-known instance for the whole of the rest of the system to call methods upon (without having to worry about instantiating the instance themselves)

Comment: Add `final` modifier to `object` to make it more related to the Singleton pattern.